# How to call next() function after condition from store has been resolved

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I want to call a next() function after a state has been changed in the store. However, I can't do this because the whole app refreshes and stops acting like SPA

```
app.router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
    store.commit('PLAY')
    next()

    if (store.state.changePage) {
      next()
    }
  })
```

Then in other component I change the state of the changePage variable

```
 const tl = (this.$options.progressTl = gsap.timeline({
    onComplete: () => {
      this.$store.commit('CHANGE_PAGE', true)

      console.log(this.$store.state.playCurtain)
      gsap.set('.clear', {
        clearProps: 'all',
      })

      this.$options.progressTl.kill()
    },
  }))
```

Does anybody know to could I call the next function in another component by any chance or how to resolve this issue?

Comment: "I can't do this because the whole app refreshes and stops acting like SPA" - why? "Then in other component I change the state of the changePage variable" - which component and how it's related to current route? Please, explain your case further. "Does anybody know to could I call the next function in another component" - it's supposed to be called in router hook. When the navigation is finished, there's no "next" you can only navigate to another route. Also, you call next() twice in beforeResolve.

Comment: I don't know why, that's why I want to know if I put next() in the if statement, the whole app reloads and stops working as SPA.

It's related in a way that I want to do this curtain effect and after the whole animation ends, it should change state of the changePage variable therefore calling next() function.

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't call next() twice. Can't say if it's the cause

Comment: That was a mistake, I deleted it but it acts the same